# Auth not working in other module laravel 4 creolab

Tags: php, laravel-4, module, hmvc

hi i create a project in hmvc architecture with creolab module in laravel 4 [here](http://creolab.hr/2013/10/modules-laravel-4-part-2/)
let say i divided my project into 3 module like example there

```
--module--
auth
shop
content
```

the scenario here user must login in auth modul first
after that they be able to access 2 module left (Shop & content)

when i try to auth protecting route in module shop or content like this example

```
Authenticating Group */
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
   Route::get('shop',  array(
    'as' => 'shop',      
    'uses' => 'App\Modules\Shop\Controllers\ShopController@getShop'
  ));
});
```

i can't access it although i already success login in modul Auth 
i already confirm it i success login with return string like this

i think the problem is here 
in my module account, my accountController contain script like this

```
public function postLogin() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ));

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return  Redirect::route('login.post')
                ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        ));

        if($auth) {
            return "login success";
            // return Redirect::intended('shop');
        }
        else {
            return  Redirect::route('login')
                    ->with('global', 'Email or Password Not Match');
        }
    }
}
```

when i return simple string (disable redirect) i got `login success`in screen 
 that indicate i already success login, but when i active redirect to another module, i got push back to login page

i check auth state with this simple script in login page like this

```
@if (Auth::check())
   {{ login }}
@else
   {{ "not login "}}
@endif
```

and got not login text 
can someone help me?

---

**@update**

```
public function postLogin() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ));

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return  Redirect::route('login.post')
                ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        ));

        if($auth) {
            return Redirect::intended('shop');
        }
        else {
            return  Redirect::route('login')
                    ->with('global', 'Email or Password Not Match');
        }
    }
}
```

---

**@2nd Update**
**route in shop module**

```
<?php

/* Authenticating Group */
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

  Route::get('shop',  array(
    'as' => 'shop',      
    'uses' => 'App\Modules\Shop\Controllers\ShopController@getShop'
  ));

  Route::post('shop',  array(
    'as' => 'shop.post',      
    'uses' => 'App\Modules\Shop\Controllers\ShopController@postShop'
  ));

  Route::post('shop-delete',  array(
    'as' => 'shop.delete',      
    'uses' => 'App\Modules\Shop\Controllers\ShopController@postShopDelete'
  ));

});
```

---

**@update my authentication filters.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
   if (Auth::guest())
   {
      if (Request::ajax())
      {
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
      }
      else
      {
        return Redirect::guest('login');
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works.

```
    if(Auth::attempt(['usernae' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')]))
    {
       return 'login success';
    }else{
        return 'login failed';
    }
```

Comment: not working too when in module shop & content i used auth protection

Comment: Can i see your `$auth`?

Comment: Delete my answer. Lol. You have two attempts

Comment: done...hahha forget to delete that...anyway do you have another idea why that happen i can't access other module with auth protection although i already login in auth module?

Comment: Can i see your routes?

Comment: Is your password stored in the database hashed?

Comment: yeah..i used `Hash::make` before store password

Comment: Can I see your Filters.php?

Comment: please see my post :D...do you need another section on my filters.php?

Comment: Is this `return Redirect::intended('driver');` in your route?

Comment: yeah my module actually `driver, company etc`...`shop and content` just for example.. that should be `shop` in here after success login

Comment: Try to put all routes that needs authentication inside the group.

Comment: hm...don't get clearly idea...can you correct my route in shop module...so i can learn from example

Comment: In your 2nd update you have `Route::group()`. Insert all your routes that requires authentication. For example: `Route::group([], function(){ all your routes here if the user is logged In});`

Comment: do you want to move this to discussion chat..i think i found out anomaly here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88672/discussion-between-neversaysblack-and-aldrin27).